# “Simple” Programming Homework

Tags: code-golf, restricted-source

Your friend has been caught sleeping in class again! As punishment, his computer science teacher has assigned him homework, knowing that he will not be able to solve it due to not having paid any attention.

The assignment seems deceiving simple at first; all that is required is to output the string:

```
John Doe
```

Unfortunately, the teacher is intent on making the simple assignment much more difficult. Since your friend was not listening when the teacher explained the concept of strings and numbers, the teacher forbids him from using any number character (0-9) or the quotes (`"`, `'`, `` ` ``).

Can you help your friend solve this problem with the shortest code possible, and save his computer science grade in the process?

Try to find the shortest code in each language!

<sub>Note: it is encouraged to try to solve this problem in languages where string/character literals exist but cannot be used due to the restrictions (most mainstream languages are like this, e.g. C++).</sub>

Comment: This is awfully close to [a previous poorly received challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/219347/56656).

Comment: And as we still not know why some serial downvoters had objections on many solutions there, personally I feel no urge to participate in another so similar challenge.

Comment: @manatwork You may find [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18715/56656) helpful.

Comment: @WheatWizard, read it last year. Read it again. Still in dark. But never mind.

Comment: (Op did post this in the sandbox for a while. Although there's no close vote this time...) although does having a lot of trivial answers imply that the challenge is terrible? FWIW the "check if two numbers are equal" and "multiply two numbers" are pretty heavily down voted too.

Comment: Why did you repost your previous question?

Comment: @expressjs123 I edited it to make it more clear. This is not the same question.

Comment: Are snippets allowed?

Answer (score 5):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 51 bytes

```powershell
#John Doe
(gc $PsCommandPath)[+$x]-replace(echo \#)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X9krPyNPwSU/lUsjPVlBJaDYOT83NzEvJSCxJEMzWlulIla3KLUgJzE5VSM1OSNfIUZZ8/9/AA)

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <strike>59</strike> 54 bytes

```powershell
$x++;$x++
-join((echo John),(echo Doe).PadLeft($x+$x))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X6VCW9saQXDpZuVn5mlopCZn5Ct45WfkaepA2C75qZp6AYkpPqlpJRra2ioVmpr//wMA)

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 56 bytes

```powershell
-join((echo John),[char](++$x-shl$x+++$x+$x),(echo Doe))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XzcrPzNPQyM1OSNfwSs/I09TJzo5I7EoVkNbW6VCtzgjR6VCG8QEIk0diDKX/FRNzf//AQ)

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 57 bytes

```powershell
-join((echo John),[char]([char](echo !)-++$x),(echo Doe))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XzcrPzNPQyM1OSNfwSs/I09TJzo5I7EoVgNKgSUUNXW1tVUqNHUgXJf8VE3N//8B)

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), The Most Trivial Solution™, 10 bytes

(I'm sorry, I said I wanted to avoid trivial solutions, but I did not know this was possible, and felt that this method might benefit PS solutions to other challenges)

```powershell
{John Doe}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/v9orPyNPwSU/tfb/fwA)

Comment: 19 bytes: `Write-Host John Doe`

Comment: @Makonede Feel free to post yourself; It's a good example for PowerShell, but I want my answer to stick with non-trivial/built-in solutions to the problem :) Thanks for pointing it out, though!

Comment: Alright, sounds good!

Comment: one more to the collection :) [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XzcrPzNPQ8dQy6JGtVo9Nd9FIS8j30s9WldXJTO2VvP/fwA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: +1 [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XzcrPzNPQ927IDNf0bUgTb1GVaFEq7JGtTo6OSOxKFZDJV7XULNW8/9/AA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: Join Doe [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X11dR11dNys/M0/dKz8jT8ElP1X9/38A "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: I'm rich [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X11dtyi1ICcxOVVdRV1H3Ss/I0/BJT9V/f9/AA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: The John Doe. First? [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X90rPyNPwSU/Vb3Gvtqw9v9/AA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: The John Doe, First [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X90rPyNPwSU/VV3L8P9/AA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: Casino Royal [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X90rPyNPwSU/VV1L0eD/fwA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: Russian roulette [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X0fdKz8jT8ElP1Vdy7SmKDEvJT/3/38A "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: Little Nightmares [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X7e4ICezRD0rPyNPISU/Vb1GtVo3Kz8zT0MlPtpAT884FiigpBKvVKOqoa4F1Kauo65VAKQ0oxU1VDK1tVVNNGNrNWuBqlTMtG2BKhWUarlUzP7/BwA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: The Count of Monte Cristo [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/3zNNQ1ElJCNVzzm/NK9Es1rdKz8jT8ElP1W99v9/AA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: Pulp Fiction [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XzcrPzNPw0BPz7xGtVrdxSs/NSNPQT1aJV7LSNVCVyVe30hbzyy2VvP/fwA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: @mazzy Haha, nice! All of those are very fun spins on printing :)

Answer (score 5):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev), <s>80</s> <s>77</s> <s>76</s> <s>65</s> <s>40</s> <s>34</s> 20 bytes

```js
_=>/John Doe/.source
```

Turns out the `_=>` might be required.

**History:**

```js
/John Doe/.source
```

Oh there's a trivial way to do it. I just wasted an hour :/

**31:**

```js
(/John Doe/+[]).slice(-~[],~[])
```

Finally found a way to get rid of that pesky `toString` :p

**37:**

```js
/John Doe/.toString().slice(-~[],~[])
```

Why use the function thing at all?

**62:**

```js
(function John_Doe(){}).name.replace(/_/,/ /.toString()[-~[]])
```

I probably should have thought about using `/ /` sooner...

**73:**

```js
(function John_Doe(){}).name.replace(/_/,{}.toString(x=true)[x-~x-~x-~x])
```

I wasted twenty minutes trying to do this character by character then remembered this.

Golfed three bytes by using `-~x`, which is the same as `+2`.

Comment: Currently, your code is a snippet. You can make it a function by just prepending `_=>`: `_=>/John Doe/.source`

Comment: @Makonede I was under the impression snippets were allowed but I'll mention that in the answer and ask for clarification in a comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

## C, 41 bytes

```
#define p(x)puts(#x)
main(){p(John Doe);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/185JTUtMy9VoUCjQrOgtKRYQ7lCkys3MTNPQ7O6QMMrPyNPwSU/VdO69v9/AA)

`#` converts a token passed to a macro to a string literal.

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), `s`, 16 bytes

```
\J\o\h\nð\D\o\eW
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=s&code=%5CJ%5Co%5Ch%5Cn%C3%B0%5CD%5Co%5CeW&inputs=&header=&footer=)

### Explained

```python
\J\o\h\n    # Push the characters J, o, h and n
ð           # Push a space
\D\o\e      # Push the characters D, o and e
W           # Wrap everything into a list. The s flag joins on newlines
```

Comment: @Downvoters why are you serial downvoting everything? Just because it's trivial doesn't mean you need to act harshly.

Comment: I also faced the same problem in answering the trivial questions, in most of the cases the downvoter doesn't reply. Anyhow cut your downvote with an upvote.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <sup><s>55</s> <s>43</s></sup> 28 bytes

Saved 12 bytes thanks to [Makonede](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/94066/makonede)!!!
Saved 15 bytes thanks to [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs)!!!

```python
print(*dict(John=[],Doe=[]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQyslM7lEwys/I882OlbHJT8VSGlq/v8PAA)

Comment: Nice, that seems to be the shortest fix here. Also, here's a 43 byte version: `John=Doe=[];print(dir()[True],dir()[False])`

Comment: @Makonede Was just fixing that and nice one - thanks! :D

Comment: 28 bytes with `print(*dict(John=[],Doe=[]))`

Comment: @ovs Nice one - thanks! :D

Comment: @tsh Both unfortunately for this challenge and fortunately as capital letters come first, Python sorts namespaces - so your suggestion prints out `Doe John`.

Answer (score 3):

## CW for languages where the program `John Doe` is valid

Feel free to add to this list if you find a solution in another language.

**NOTE:** Text editors have been excluded as there are way too many of them.

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////)

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal)

## [GS2](https://github.com/nooodl/gs2)

## [HTML](https://html.spec.whatwg.org)

## [Keg](https://github.com/Lyxal/Keg)

## [PHP](https://php.net)

## [Quine](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Quine_(programming_language))

## [Text](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Text)

Comment: I'm not sure, so I won't add it yet, but what about `vim -y`?

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
”„ÐÒ«
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcPcRw3zDk84POnQ6v//AQ)

```
”„ÐÒ«  # full program
”„ÐÒ«  # push "John Doe"
       # implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java, 166 bytes

```
$->{class John_Doe{}final char o=Byte.MAX_VALUE/Byte.MAX_VALUE,t=o+o,f=t+t+o,T=f+f,u=T*T-f,s=f*(f+o)+t;System.out.print(John_Doe.class.getSimpleName().replace(u,s));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVDLTsMwELznK3zgYOdhPiC4UnlcEOWSUCEhVBnXTh0cO7LXlaoo3x4MhUrsZTSzo53d7fmRV/3@c9HD6DygPnEaQRuqohWgnaV5nY3xw2iBhOEhoA3XFk0ZSvWrB@CQ4Oj0Hg2pixvw2nZv74j7LpCz97vunA1xkP5mm6wrJNhyVa2m89hHd7C7eyenWWnLDRIH7pFjtyeQdLN@3W3XTy8P1/9pCcwVrlQMCkjYMlWoMrI2bytVBqZyrApHCqibUwA5UBeBjmk1wH9p9CecdhKa9AEjn/kgMaFejoYLiWMZCKnnpb6cICgXQo6AbTSGnPU5m5cv)

## Java, 192 bytes

```
a->{final char O=Byte.MAX_VALUE/Byte.MAX_VALUE,T=O+O,t=T+O,F=t+T,S=F+T,Z=F+F,Y=Z*Z,o=Y+Z+O,J=S*Z+T+T,h=Y+T+T,n=Y+Z,$=Z*t+T,D=F*Z+Z+F+t,e=Y+O;System.out.print(String.valueOf(J)+o+h+n+$+D+o+e);}
```

This uses `Byte.MAX_VALUE/Byte.MAX_VALUE` to obtain the number `1` and then uses it to construct the ASCII codes of all the characters in the string. `final` is needed so that casts from `int` to `char` are not necessary.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY/BboMwEETv@QofcgDsuB9AHSltyiFqxAEaNVRV5RITTI2NYB0pivLtdFGiSt3DrHfe@DCNPMlFc/gZddu5HkiDN/egDa@8LUE7y6N41vlvo0tSGjkMZCu1JZcZwbn7A0jAdXL6QFqkQQa9tsePTyL74xDestM8Ozv4VvWPO4wuSSVGuVheKm2lIWUte5KKpzMovl29f@1Wr28vD/9PlouUpgxEjpoIoDnLRIJaoCZsL4qoYE7saYF8I7KooDnSGp1p24mwOaamn2uRIC9oQoEpJGmcnQdQLXceeIcF4N6Dn6TxKq2CTUgdramlc7rGlwrj6xj/lau4LEvVQWC9MeHNv86u4y8)

Comment: The 41 bytes version is not valid as digits are not allowed either.

Comment: @Laikoni Good catch.

Comment: You can use pre-existing public variables to get the space char value (or use a field, which auto initializes itself to 0, and shift its bits around like `++x>>++x>>++x`, 1<<2<<3=32). I got it to [134 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220384/94107)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) -M5.10.0, 15 bytes

```perl
say q(John Doe)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVKhUMMrPyNPwSU/VfP//3/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDfQMAA) I don't know whether -M5.10.0 is optimal, I just cargo culted it from a random Perl answer.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, 32 bytes

```
_=>(/John Doe/+[]).slice(-~_,~_)
```

When the function is called without arguments, the first argument will be `undefined` and `~undefined` produces `-1`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/ifZvs/3tZOQ98rPyNPwSU/VV87OlZTrzgnMzlVQ7cuXqcuXvN/cn5ecX5Oql5OfrpGmoam5n8A)

*Thanks to [tsh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/44718) for the idea*

## JavaScript (V8), 39 bytes

```
print(...Object.keys({John:[],Doe:[]}))
```

`print` uses a space to separate arguments when printing.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/v6AoM69EQ09Pzz8pKzW5RC87tbJYo9orPyPPKjpWxyU/FUjVamr@/w8A)

Comment: `x=>(/Jone Doe/+[]).slice(-~x,~x)` 32 bytes

Comment: @tsh Nice one.​

Comment: Interesting approach with the `print` and `Object.keys`, probably the most creative answer so far! I've also found a [17 byte](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220121/79857) JS solution a few days ago, although it's a snippet (can be made into a function for 20 bytes).

Answer (score 1):

## [Bubblegum](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Bubblegum), <s>10</s> 7 bytes

*-3 bytes by [@tsh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/44718/tsh).*

```
´H&ÒF
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypNSspJTS/N/f/fAAqsFAySkkwUTCyMzBQMjFKMFEzMFBT09DzU9PTc/v8HAA) This program gets converted to base 256, then to base 96, and each digit \$n\$ gets replaced with the \$n\$th printable ASCII character. Hexdump:

```
00000000: 0bb4 4826 02d2 46  ..H&..F
```

Comment: 7 bytes: [0bb4482602d246](https://tio.run/##SypNSspJTS/N/f/fAAqsFAySkkwUTCyMzBQMjFKMFEzMFHAAPT0PNT09t///AQ)

Comment: The 7 bytes version is not a zip stream, but a base 96 to base 256 encoding.

Answer (score 1):

## Windows Batch, 13 bytes

```cmd
echo John Doe
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
“®ƊʠỌḂŒ»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARwA4/9qZWxsef//4oCcwq7Gisqg4buM4biCxZLCu///)

The `“` at the beginning isn't defined as a quote in the challenge, so Id say this is valid.

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 19 bytes

```ps
Write-Host John Doe
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNydFNzi9K/f8/vCizJFXXI7@4RMErPyNPwSUfKAgA)

```ps
Write-Host John Doe  # full program
Write-Host           # output...
           John Doe  # literal
```

Answer (score 1):

## Notepad / Gedit, 15 keystrokes

```
SHIFT+J
o
SHIFT+LEFT ARROW
CTRL+C
RIGHT ARROW
h
n

D
CTRL+V
e
```

## Notepad / Gedit (Boring solution), 8 keystrokes

```
J
o
h
n

D
o
e
```

Comment: If capitals count as one keystroke, shouldn't `SHIFT+J` be `J`?

Answer (score 1):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 91 bytes

```
-[------->+<]>+.[-->+++<]>.-------.++++++.-[->+++++<]>-.++[->++<]>.[--->+<]>+++.----------.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fN1oXAuy0bWLttPWiQSxtEFsPKqGnDQZ6QJV2YBZQDiQI5oLURcN1g1TBgd7//wA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/), 38 bytes

```julia
print(:John,Char(ceil(π*π*π)),:Doe)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/v6AoM69Ew8orPyNPxzkjsUgjOTUzR@N8gxYYaWrqWLnkp2r@/w8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 134 bytes

```java
class John{public static void main(String[]z){System.out.print(John.class.getName()+(char)Float.SIZE+Doe.class.getName());}}enum Doe{}
```

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 131 bytes

```java
interface John{static void main(String[]z){System.out.print(John.class.getName()+(char)Float.SIZE+Doe.class.getName());}}enum Doe{}
```

This is an everything java solution - count in the whole file, header and footer. No tio.run link because it depends on the class name, which must be `John` in this case. In Java 8+ you can make it an `interface` and omit `public` in the main method for -3.

`Float.SIZE` and `Integer.SIZE` return `32`, the char code for a space. In this case, `getName()`, `getTypeName()`, `getSimpleName()`, and `getCanonicalName()` will all return just the desired name part of the class/enum. You can make `John` an `enum` for -1, but it would require an extra `;` at the start to declare the enum objects, +1, making it equal length.

You can run this to verify whether it prints the correct String (and that the space character is an actual space, because doing `(char)0`, for example, will leave a blank spot without it technically being a space):

```java
interface John { // or class
    public static void main(String[]z) {
        System.out.print((John.class.getName() + (char) Float.SIZE + Doe.class.getName())
            .equals("John Doe"));
        }
    }
enum Doe{}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pxem](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pxem), 10 bytes of file name + 0 bytes of content = 10 bytes

- Filename: `John Doe.p`
- Content is empty

What a low effort.

Answer (score 1):

## [Deadfish~](https://github.com/TryItOnline/deadfish-), 70 bytes

```
{i}dds{i}c{iiii}dddc{d}iiiciiiiiic{{d}ii}iic{iii}iiiiiic{iiii}iiic{d}c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYoxDgAgDAJf5KMMaGR2bPr2WqsMwBE4Oqf2ahEmJ3c6TKkEwuhZoRKs0G9T5Vv14b4RcQA)

It somehow beats Java!

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 8 bytes

```
«:L∞I\«ǐ
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C2%AB%3AL%E2%88%9EI%5C%C2%AB%C7%90&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Explanation:

```
«:L∞I\«   # Base-256 compressed "john doe"
       ǐ  # Convert To Title Case
          # Implicit output
```

Vyxal doesn't support capital letters in compressed strings, which is why the `ǐ` command is needed.

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net), 8 bytes

```php
John Doe
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fKz8jT8ElP/X/fwA)

```php
John Doe  # full program
John Doe  # no leading <?, so outputs source
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2), <s>56</s> 14+8=22 bytes

```py
print __file__
```

Must be saved in a file called `John Doe` in the root directory. However, the path may not even contain a single `/` for this to work. Therefore, this file's full path should be only `John Doe`, and not `/John Doe` or `C:/John Doe`. Theoretically possible but not sure how in practice.

NB: Adding the lengths of the file name and the code was somehow the shortest approach I could find to this challenge (in Python).

Comment: [This answer was posted before this loophole was banned, but this would now be invalid](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20927)

Answer (score -2):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash), 13 bytes

```sh
echo John Doe
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I1/BKz8jT8ElP/X/fwA)

```sh
echo John Doe  # full program
echo           # output...
     John Doe  # literal
```

Comment: Combine your Batch and this answer, they are polygots

Comment: I know, but they're different languages.